# Laravel Eloquent: How to filter a single row out when two conditions (one from the table, and one from parent table) are true?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
OrderPayments::leftJoin('.orders','.orders.id', 'order_payments.orderid')
->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('orders.type', '!=', '1')
                    ->where('order_payments.item_id', '!=', '1');
            })
->where(somethingelse...)
```

This is the code. An order may have more than 1 order_payments.

I only want to filter out the row that both has the orders.type as 1 and order_payments.item_id as 1. But if in the same order, there is another order_payments that has item_id as 2, I want to show that but not the previous one.

I used this code, but it shows no data, even though there should be. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a relation defined in the models between `OrderPayment.php` and `Order.php`?

Comment: @Refilon Yes, orderpayment has a belongsto order in the model.

Comment: Okay, you could use the `whereHas` function then. `OrderPayments::whereHas('order', function ($q) { $q->where('some_order_field', '=', 'value'; )})->where('some_order_payment_field', '=', 'value');`

Comment: @Refilon Ah I want to show all rows that are not those conditions ('orders.type', '!=', '1' and 'order_payments.item_id', '!=', '1')? If I change the = to != in your answer, it shows me no data, even though the order_payments that has item_id as 2 and orders.type as 1  should be shown.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code of the Order model and the OrderPayment model?